# Return in array

Tags: php

I have these php lines:

```
<?php
$start_text = '<username="';
$end_text = '" userid=';
$source = file_get_contents('http://mysites/users.xml');
$start_pos = strpos($source, $start_text) + strlen($start_text);
$end_pos = strpos($source, $end_text) - $start_pos;
$found_text = substr($source, $start_pos, $end_pos);
echo $found_text;
?>
```

I want to see just the names from entire file, but it shows me just the first name. I want to see all names.

I think it is something like: `foreach ($found_text as $username)`.... but here I am stuck.

---

---

**Update from OP post, below:**

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("users.xml");

  foreach ($xml->children() as $child)
  {
        foreach($child->attributes() as $a => $b)
        {
          echo $a,'="',$b,"\"</br>";

        }


               foreach ($child->children() as $child2)
    {

                foreach($child2->attributes() as $c => $d)
        {
          echo "<font color='red'>".$c,'="',$d,"\"</font></br>";
        }

    }
  }
?>
```

with this code, i receive all details about my users, but from all these details i want to see just 2 or 3

Now i see :

```
name="xxx"
type="default"
can_accept="true"
can_cancel="false"
image="avatars/trophy.png"
title="starter"
........etc
```

Another details from the same user "Red color(defined on script)"

```
reward_value="200"
reward_qty="1"
expiration_date="12/07/2012"
.....etc
```

what i want to see?

i.e  first line from first column "`name="xxx`" & `expiration_date="12/07/2012`" from second column

Comment: it looks like you're trying to parse an XML file. If that's true, then (although it may be extra work), I suggest using a XML parser. That way, if you get dodgy input your whole system won't collapse.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to repeat the loop, using the 3rd parameter, `offset`, of the [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function. That way, you can look for a new name each time.

Something like this (untested)

```
<?php
$start_text = '<username="';
$end_text = '" userid=';
$source = file_get_contents('http://mysites/users.xml');
$offset = 0;
while (false !== ($start_pos = strpos($source, $start_text, $offset)))
{
    $start_pos += strlen($start_text);
    $end_pos = strpos($source, $end_text, $offset);
    $offset = $end_pos;
    $text_length = $end_pos - $start_pos;
    $found_text = substr($source, $start_pos, $text_length);
    echo $found_text;
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks good (+1), except `$start_pos` will effectively always be bool `TRUE` unless you wrap the assignment in parens - at the moment it will always be the result of a comparison operation, and since this is a while condition, it will always be `TRUE` or it won't be executed.

Comment: i tried with your code (i have modified your "endpos" to end_pos :) but i receive just first name from all names for many times(unlimited times) :) & also "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in I:\xampp\htdocs\alt.php on line 12" on that line is $offset = $end_pos;

Comment: That's actually because end_pos wasn't really the end position, but the length of the text to copy. Therefor, $offset got the wrong value too (the length of the last text to be precise). I've changed this piece of code, to leave end_pos alone and introduce a new variable text_length. I also changed the condition in the while loop as advised by DaveRandom.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use [XMLReader](http://php.net/xmlreader) or [DOM](http://php.net/dom) or [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) to read XML files. If you don't see the necessity, try the following regular expressions approach to retrieve all usernames:

```
<?php

$xml = '<xml><username="hello" userid="123" /> <something /> <username="foobar" userid="333" /></xml>';
if (preg_match_all('#<username="(?<name>[^"]+)"#', $xml, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
  var_dump($matches['name']);
} else {
  echo 'no <username="" found';
}
```